# Counting distinct functions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I would like to get help with the following question:

> A and B are integers (A ≤ B). How many distinct functions exist from
>   the type of [A...B] → [A..B] such that f(x) ≤ x for all x in the
>   domain?

In order to find the amount of distinction functions, we should use the following formula when n is the cardinality of the domain and r is the cardinality of the codomain: r^n.
However, I find it confusing to generalize a solution for the question.
Would be happy for any kind of assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The particular values are irrelevant, so let's assume that the domain and range are both $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$. You are saying that there is no choice for $f(1)$ it must be 1. There are 2 choices for $f(2)$, namely 1 and 2, and so on. So $n!$ possible functions in total.